# React typescript: .d.ts files in multiple folders, export all types/interfaces within index.ts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react project, I have several config folders:

```
-config
  -api/
    |index.ts
    |types.d.ts
  -routes/
    |index.ts
    |types.d.ts
...
```

In `api/index.ts` for example, I can import types needed with `import {SomeType} from './types`.

Now in other component pages, I'd like to import those types with `import {SomeType} from config/api`, so I tried exporting all types in `api/index.ts` with `export * from './types'`, but got error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types' in ...`.

What is the correct way to achieve this? Is this even possible? Or maybe there're some workarounds?

packages:

- "typescript": "^4.0.3",
- "react": "^18.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to use index.ts as a barrel file.

In order to do that you need to export each named export from types.

You don't need to import them before exporting them - you can export them directly.

In index.ts something like :

```
export { SomeType, SomeOtherType } from './types';
```